# Use user input in a function inside script

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing

I have a PowerShell script in which I want to execute a function with the parameters which are provided on the commandline:

```
Param(
  [string]$param1
  [string]$param2
)

Write-Host $param1

function Run ([string]$param1, [string]$param2){
  New $param1
  New2 $param2
}

function New ([string]$param1){
  Write-Host $param1
}

function new2 ([string]$param2){
  Write-Host $param2
}

Run
```

But it didn't work. The `Run` fuction did not get the parameters from which I've provided:

```
./script.ps1 -$param1="hello" -$param2="hello2"
```

The `Write-Host` part outside the functions worked. But the parameters aren't passed to my `Run` function.

Comment: How about you run the script yourself instead of asking other people to do it for you? The invocation would be `my-script.ps1 -param1 "hello" -param2 "hello2"`, though.

Comment: It's more about  the approach. Is it the right approach to work like this if you want to provide input paramters to functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Run` function is not working as you expect because you aren't passing the parameters to it.

Update the last line in your script to:

```
Run -param1 $param1 -param2 $param2
```

EDIT: The way you are writing and using/linking your functions looks fine. The param names could be a bit more descriptive, but I assume this is example code so this may not be relevant in your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

For one thing, the script invocation should look like this:

```
my-script.ps1 -param1 "hello" -param2 "hello2"
```

Also, you need to actually pass the script parameters to the `Run` function. Probably the best way to do this is to [splat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) the [automatic variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) `$PSBoundParameters`:

```
Run @PSBoundParameters
```

With that said, whether or not to wrap the main script code in a function is more or less a matter of personal opinion and how you intend to use the script.

**Con:** You need to duplicate the script parameters for the `Run` function and pass the script arguments.

**Pro:** It's a bit cleaner, because virtually all code is encapsulated. Also, it allows you to both invoke the script directly and use it as a library if you condionally execute the `Run` function:

```
if ($MyInvocation.Line.Split()[0] -ne '.') {
  Run @PSBoundParameters
}
```

That way you import the functions when [dot-sourcing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) the script, and invoke the `Run` function with the script parameters when executing the script.